# Continue execution of content script after page redirects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an issue with a Chrome extension that I'm building. I have the extension set to use a content script to scrape info from one webpage, `console.log` the info, redirect to another page, and `console.log` the data once the next page loads. Unfortunately, the extension logs the first time, but the execution just stops after the new page is loaded. Here is my code:

```
var terms = document.getElementsByClassName('SetPage-termsList')[0].innerText;
alert(terms);
document.getElementsByClassName('UIHeading')[0].style.color = 'red';
var menubuttons = document.getElementsByClassName('SetPageModeButton-link');
var learnbutton = menubuttons[0];
var lochref = window.location.href;
var lhpat = /https:\/\/quizlet.com\/\d+\//i;
var urlbase = lochref.match(lhpat)[0];
var learnurl = urlbase + "learn";
location.replace(learnurl);
await sleep(5000);
console.log(terms);
```

This is supposed to be a bot for Quizlet that I am making, and the extension is to be activated on the homepage of any specific set. Right now, it changes the color of the set title to red (debug purposes) and then redirects to the new page. It doesn't actually log the terms variable when it hits the new page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The entire execution context is recreated and the content scripts run when the page is [re]loaded. You can't "continue" running them. You can only run them anew e.g. by using chrome.tabs.executeScript in the background page script.

Comment: If you want to store the previous data or states, you can use local storage. Also, you can communicate with background script.